# How can I check/see the inside operations and calculations of any Keras (Dense, Conv1D, LSTM) layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, architecture, layer, unfold

I have a question about the architecture of the Keras layers. About kind of unfolding the architecture of the layer. For example, I would like to see the main equation used for the Dense layer in Keras, how the n. of neurons, activation function, and bias are tied to each other. This seems pretty simple in logical understating for the Dense layer. However, finding out the tfa.ESN layer multiplication inside the corresponding layer, for instance, would be very helpful for me.

Thanks to everyone,
J

Comment: You can check their code on github. [like this link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras/layers) (you can find the Dense layer in core.py).

Comment: Yes, definitely. Found it. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, can I unfold it in Python still? This might be very helpful as well. Can I reach the layer class directly by using the command terminal?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that